# Jetpack Compose navigate for result

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using the Jetpack Navigation library with the Compose version. I'm setting up navigation like it's shown [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

I want to be able to navigate from screen A to screen B. Once B does something and pops off the back stack, it will then return a result that screen A can access.

I found a way to do this using Activities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721218/jetpack-compose-launch-activityresultcontract-request-from-composable-function) but I want to avoid creating any extra activities and do this in compose.

Comment: The ability to [return a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) also works in Navigation Compose; it is a core part of Navigation.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the Composable that you want to return data, you can do the following:

```kotlin
navController.previousBackStackEntry
    ?.savedStateHandle
    ?.set("your_key", "your_value")
navController.popBackStack()
```

and then, from the source Composable, you can listen for changes using a `LiveData`.

```
val secondScreenResult = navController.currentBackStackEntry
    ?.savedStateHandle
    ?.getLiveData<String>("your_key")?.observeAsState()
...
secondScreenResult?.value?.let {
    // Read the result
}
```

Comment: Did you actually try it out? Because for me the receiving value is always `null`.

Comment: Your answer saved my time. Thanks

Comment: don't forget remove your key when you consumed.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the SavedStateHandle that is in the ViewModel rather than listening in the composable?

Comment: @ScottCooper Yes, see my post below.

Comment: You have to add `implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"` to gradle for `observeAsState()` to work (replace `$compose_version` with the actual version).

Comment: What if I am traversing through A>B>C and I want to return data from C to A, how do i Do that as previousBackStackEntry will give me entry for B not A

Comment: if you need to return some data from C to A, you should return from C to B, then return from B to A. But if you pop B when you call C, then A would be the previous backstack of C, so it should work.

Answer (score 11):

If you need only once get value, you need remove value after usage:

```
val screenResultState = navController.currentBackStackEntry
    ?.savedStateHandle
    ?.getLiveData<String>("some_key")?.observeAsState()

screenResultState?.value?.let {
    ...
    // make something, for example `viewModel.onResult(it)`
    ...
    //removing used value
    navController.currentBackStackEntry
        ?.savedStateHandle
        ?.remove<String>("some_key")
}
```

I also extract it in function (for JetPack Compose)

```
@Composable
fun <T> NavController.GetOnceResult(keyResult: String, onResult: (T) -> Unit){
    val valueScreenResult =  currentBackStackEntry
        ?.savedStateHandle
        ?.getLiveData<T>(keyResult)?.observeAsState()

    valueScreenResult?.value?.let {
        onResult(it)
       
        currentBackStackEntry
            ?.savedStateHandle
            ?.remove<T>(keyResult)
    }
}
```

you can copy it to your project and use like this:

```
navController.GetOnceResult<String>("some_key"){
    ...
    // make something
}
```

Comment: `?.remove<Long>` should be `?.remove<T>`

Comment: Thanks, Olaf Achthoven, you are right.

Comment: there is a nuance: removing key from the state handle remove the live data subscription. So, it's better to set key to null:

```
 @Composable
fun <T : Parcelable> NavController.GetOnceResult(key: String, onResult: (T) -> Unit) {
    val state = (currentBackStackEntry ?: return)
        .savedStateHandle
        .getLiveData<T>(key).observeAsState()
    if (state.value == null) return
    state.value?.also {
        onResult(it)
        currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, null)
    }
}
```

Comment: But you can't use it inside the viewmodel, cause it is a composable function.

Comment: Good point by https://stackoverflow.com/users/691993/oleksii-malovanyi. I've added an answer with more detail, because I found that rather than just a nuisance, I was actually getting duplicate observations.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use NavController inside compose screen, you should pass only the data to your compose screen but not NavController

Answer (score 4):

The top answer is good enough for the most situations, but I find it isn't easy to work with a `ViewModel` if you want to do something in a method of `ViewModel`. Instead of using a `LiveData` or a `Flow` to observe the result from the called screen, I use the callback to solve this problem.

I hope my answer can help some people.

```kotlin
import androidx.navigation.NavController

/**
 * The navigation result callback between two call screens.
 */
typealias NavResultCallback<T> = (T) -> Unit

// A SavedStateHandle key is used to set/get NavResultCallback<T>
private const val NavResultCallbackKey = "NavResultCallbackKey"

/**
 * Set the navigation result callback on calling screen.
 *
 * @param callback The navigation result callback.
 */
fun <T> NavController.setNavResultCallback(callback: NavResultCallback<T>) {
    currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(NavResultCallbackKey, callback)
}

/**
 *  Get the navigation result callback on called screen.
 *
 * @return The navigation result callback if the previous backstack entry exists
 */
fun <T> NavController.getNavResultCallback(): NavResultCallback<T>? {
    return previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.remove(NavResultCallbackKey)
}

/**
 *  Attempts to pop the controller's back stack and returns the result.
 *
 * @param result the navigation result
 */
fun <T> NavController.popBackStackWithResult(result: T) {
    getNavResultCallback<T>()?.invoke(result)
    popBackStack()
}

/**
 * Navigate to a route in the current NavGraph. If an invalid route is given, an
 * [IllegalArgumentException] will be thrown.
 *
 * @param route route for the destination
 * @param navResultCallback the navigation result callback
 * @param navOptions special options for this navigation operation
 * @param navigatorExtras extras to pass to the [Navigator]
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the given route is invalid
 */
fun <T> NavController.navigateForResult(
    route: String,
    navResultCallback: NavResultCallback<T>,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null,
    navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras? = null
) {
    setNavResultCallback(navResultCallback)
    navigate(route, navOptions, navigatorExtras)
}

/**
 * Navigate to a route in the current NavGraph. If an invalid route is given, an
 * [IllegalArgumentException] will be thrown.
 *
 * @param route route for the destination
 * @param navResultCallback the navigation result callback
 * @param builder DSL for constructing a new [NavOptions]
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the given route is invalid
 */
fun <T> NavController.navigateForResult(
    route: String,
    navResultCallback: NavResultCallback<T>,
    builder: NavOptionsBuilder.() -> Unit
) {
    setNavResultCallback(navResultCallback)
    navigate(route, builder)
}
```

A example of usage:

```kotlin
fun NavGraphBuilder.addExampleGraph(navController: NavController) {
    composable(FirstScreenRoute) {
        FirstScreen(
            openSecondScreen = { navResultCallback ->
                navController.navigateForResult(SecondScreenRoute, navResultCallback = navResultCallback)
            },
            ... // other parameters
        )
    }

    composable(SecondScreenRoute) {
        SecondScreen(
            onConfirm = { result: T ->  // Replace T with your return type
                navController.popBackStackWithResult(result)
            },
            onCancel = navController::navigateUp,
            ... // other parameters
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This crashes if your callback if e.g. a viewmodel method. The way to reproduce: go to ResultScreen, then switch to another app and then switch back 

You're getting `NotSerializableException`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result without a LiveData or a Flow, you can use `savedStateHandle.remove` method. I think this is the easier way:

```kotlin
val secondResult = appNavController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.remove<Data?>("data")
secondResult?.let { data ->
    Log.d(TAG, "Data result: $data")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for jetpack compose you must use `Flow` with  `collectAsState` for get result:

```
navController.currentBackStackEntry
?.savedStateHandle?.getStateFlow<Boolean?>("refresh", false)
?.collectAsState()?.value?.let {
if (it)screenVM.refresh() }
```

also you can remove Entry with add this after `screenVM.refresh()`:

```
 navController.currentBackStackEntry
                ?.savedStateHandle ?.set("refresh", false)
```

Answer (score 0):

add dependency

```
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
```

On the Sender screen set a key value pair to send back to the caller screen, I use a Boolean with key name of "key" value true

```
navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", true)
```

navigate up

```
navController.navigateUp()
```

The receiver screen (caller) listens to the results and then remove it:

```
 val result =  navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle
    ?.getLiveData<Boolean>("key")?.observeAsState()
result?.value?.let {
    navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle
        ?.remove<Boolean>("key")
}
```

First Screen

```
@Composable fun FirstScreen(navController: NavController){

val result =  navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle
    ?.getLiveData<Boolean>("key")?.observeAsState()
result?.value?.let {
    navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle
        ?.remove<Boolean>("key")
}

Button(onClick = {
    navController.navigateUp("secondScreen")
}) {
    "Open second screen"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return from PageC to PageA and pop pageB without return to it i found solution :

wait for result from screenA

```
composable("ScreenA") {
  val savedStateHandle = navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle
  val result by savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("key").collectAsState()
  ScreenA(result)
}
```

Return value from screen3

```
  navController.apply {
            backQueue.firstOrNull { it.destination.route == route }?.savedStateHandle?.set("key",true) //
            popBackStack(route, inclusive)
        }
```

after you get your the desired answer
delete it from page3 cus you save it on saveStateHandle of the page

```
savedStateHandle.remove<Boolean>("key")
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [nglauber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837741/613482), I found I was getting repeated observations of the same result, until I switched from calling `SavedStateHandle.remove()` to setting the value of the `LiveData` to `null` instead.

```
@Composable
fun <T> NavBackStackEntry.GetOnceResult(resultKey: String, onResult: (T) -> Unit) {
    val resultLiveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<T>(resultKey)
    resultLiveData.observeAsState().value?.let {
        resultLiveData.value = null
        onResult(it)
    }
}
```

See, `SavedStateHandle.getLiveData()` actually returns a `MutableLiveData`, rather than just a generic `LiveData`. I was quite surprised as first, until I realized that this must be *intentional*, to *let* you modify the saved state via the `MutableLiveData` (which it does in fact do, as opposed to simply modifying the `LiveData` itself).

I got this idea when I saw the documentation for `SavedStateHandle.remove()`:

> Removes a value associated with the given key. If there is a LiveData and/or StateFlow associated with the given key, they will be removed as well.
> All changes to androidx.lifecycle.LiveDatas or StateFlows previously returned by SavedStateHandle.getLiveData or getStateFlow won't be reflected in the saved state. Also that LiveData or StateFlow won't receive any updates about new values associated by the given key.

I added some logging to confirm that while normally, the call to `getLiveData()` on each recomposition returns the same `LiveData` instance again, calling `SavedStateHandle.remove()` causes it to subsequently return a different `LiveData` (which gives you the old value, causing the duplicate observation).

Answer (score -1):

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
composable("A") {
    val viewmodel: AViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    AScreen()
}
composable("B") {
    val viewmodel: BViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val previousViewmodel: AViewModel? = navController
        .previousBackStackEntry?.let {
            hiltViewModel(it)
        }
    BScreen(
       back = { navController.navigateUp() },
       backWhitResult = { arg ->
           previousViewmodel?.something(arg)
       }
    )
}
```