# Jetpack compose - How to do popBackStack with arguments?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have this scenario in which the user clicks on a button in composable **A** then selects an item from the list from composable **B** and selects another item from the list from composable **C**.

My problem is when I select an item from screen **C** I want to navigate back to screen **A** with whatever I selected in **B** & **C**. But popBackStack doesn't work when arguments are given.

Here is the code,

```kotlin
navController.popBackStack(route = Screen.SelectPlan.route + "?regionId=${region.id}&operatorId=${operator.id}")
```

Right now, I see that popBackStack does take a route argument, but converts it to a hashcode to navigate back instead of creating a Uri-like navigate function.

Comment: Are you using the **exact** `route` string you use when you created your `composable` destination? That's the route it is looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose navigate for result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837132/jetpack-compose-navigate-for-result)

Comment: @ianhanniballake 
**This is whats in the backQueue of NavController:**
select_plan?operatorName={operatorName}&operatorId={operatorId}&regionName={regionName}&regionId={regionId}

**This is what I am using for popBackStack route:**
select_plan?operatorName=Jio&operatorId=0&regionName=Maharashtra & Goa (Incl. Nagpur)&regionId=13

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug in the SDK, basically popBackStack converts this to hashcode
```select_plan?operatorName=Jio&operatorId=0&regionName=Maharashtra & Goa (Incl. Nagpur)&regionId=13``` and treats this as an **id**, which definitely has to be different than the one generated from ```select_plan?operatorName={operatorName}&operatorId={operatorId}&regionName={regionName}&regionId={regionId}```

and thus is failed to find the destination by id

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue and have just discovered the solution for myself.

When you navigate to a destination, using args like so:

```
val arg1 = "someValue"
val arg2 = "someOtherValue"
navController.navigate("Destination/$arg1/$arg2")
```

... this `route` is stored in the newly created backstack entry, not with the *values* of those args, but with their *names* as assigned in your `NavHost`.

Assume my `NavHost` contains a `composable` with a route of `Destination/{arg1}/{arg2}`.

If the `.navigate()` call in my previous example is executed, an entry will be added to the backstack with this route `Destination/{arg1}/{arg2}`, ***not*** this route `Destination/someValue/someOtherValue`.

You didn't provide your `NavHost` in the post, but if you replace the values of those args in the call to `.popBackStack()` with their names you assign in your `NavHost`, it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug and it bothered me for a long time. After a long time of research and reading the `navigation` source code, I wrote my own extension function `NavController.popBackStack` to fix this problem. It is tricky but works for me. Also note that this version of extension function does not support the `inclusive` and `saveState` options (due to the current navigation API limitation), so you can't `restoreState` when you return to the current destination.

```kotlin
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.navigation.NavController

fun NavController.popBackStack(route: String): Boolean {
    if (backQueue.isEmpty()) {
        return false
    }

    var found = false
    var popCount = 0
    val iterator = backQueue.reversed().iterator()
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        val entry = iterator.next()
        popCount++
        val intent = entry
            .arguments
            ?.get("android-support-nav:controller:deepLinkIntent") as Intent?
        if (intent?.data?.toString() == "android-app://androidx.navigation/$route") {
            found = true
            break
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        navigate(route) {
            while (popCount-- > 0) {
                popBackStack()
            }
        }
    }
    return found
}
```

Comment: Seems to still be an issue, this solution worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Try put "/" instead of ?

```
 navController.popBackStack(route = Screen.SelectPlan.route + "/regionId=${region.id}&operatorId=${operator.id}")
```

Comment: this is not working