# How to handle behavior similar to onActivityResult in compose navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a setup where I want to navigate to a composable for result and then depending on that result I want to launch another composable from the parent.
Here is the setup

ScreenA launches Screen B for result (user does something in screenB) -> ScreenB sets a result and pops itself from the stack -> ScreenA looks at the result and depending on the value launches ScreenC.

The issue here is that the observer I have set on the result keeps firing off infinitely once the result is set by ScreenB.

Here is a simplified version of my setup:

```
fun AppNavHost(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "ScreenA",
    ) {
        composable("ScreenA") {
            ScreenA(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate("ScreenB")
                }
            )
            val result = navController.currentBackStackEntry
                ?.savedStateHandle
                ?.getLiveData<String>("key")
                ?.observeAsState()
            result?.value?.let { str ->
                // This seems to not remove the key or at least
                // the live data value is not nulled out
                navController.currentBackStackEntry
                    ?.savedStateHandle
                    ?.remove<String>("key")
                if (str == "result") {
                    // This condition hits infinitely
                    navController.navigate("ScreenC")
                    // This logs infinitely
                    Log.d("TAG", "found result: $str")
                }
            }
        }
        composable("ScreenB") {
            ScreenB(
                onClick = {
                    navController.previousBackStackEntry
                        ?.savedStateHandle
                        ?.set("key", "result")
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
            )
        }
        composable("ScreenC") { ScreenC() }
    }
}
```

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837741/2517849) and my setup here is similar.  How can I fix this behavior so the result of ScreenB is only read once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LaunchedEffect to avoid multiple calls to navigate at the recomposition level.

```
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "ScreenA",
) {
    composable("ScreenA") {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate("ScreenB")
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Text("Go to Screen B")
        }
        val result = navController.currentBackStackEntry
            ?.savedStateHandle
            ?.getLiveData<String>("key")
            ?.observeAsState()
        result?.value?.let { str ->
            navController.currentBackStackEntry
                ?.savedStateHandle
                ?.remove<String>("key")
            LaunchedEffect(str) {
                if (str == "result") {
                    navController.navigate("ScreenC")
                    Log.d("TAG", "found result: $str")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    composable("ScreenB") {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.previousBackStackEntry
                    ?.savedStateHandle
                    ?.set("key", "result")
                navController.popBackStack()
            }
        ) {
            Text("Screen B")
        }
    }
     composable("ScreenC") { ScreenC() }
}
```